# Push notification and phone authentication services besides Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, authentication, push-notification

My app is not using Firebase for its database and APIs. Now I need to add Push Notifications and Phone Authentication to my app. Should I use Firebase or is there a better way? If I have to use FCM and Firebase Auth, would it be possible if I keep using my own custom database and APIs along with FCM and Firebase Auth, instead of having to use Firebase APIs for all transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using FCM REST API `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`